# Add Row and Column Dynamically to a Google Column Chart

Tags: javascript, dynamic, google-visualization

My problem is a bit similar with as in [How to dynamically add rows/columns to a Google Column Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415689/how-to-dynamically-add-rows-columns-to-a-google-column-chart/61072059#61072059), but my data structure is a bit different.

Instead of data like this

```
['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses' , 'Other'],
['2004',  1000,      400     ,  232   ],
['2005',  1170,      460    ,  421   ],
```

my data is like this:

[image: array structure]

I have done the add column part.

```
var keys = Object.keys(columnsIn);
var last = keys[keys.length - 1];
             // in this case the first column is of type 'string'.
            dataTable.addColumn('string', last); //get last key as ESN will be in last column. 
            // all other columns are of type 'number'.
            for (var i = 0; i < numCols-1; i++){
                dataTable.addColumn('number', keys[i]); 
            }
```

I am having difficulties with add row.

Comment: use proper tags and  provide text and not images of code. See [ask]

Comment: "I am having difficulties with add row." - what are those difficulties?

Comment: @mkrieger1 hi.. i manage to solve this already based on solution below. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert array of objects to a 2D array using [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [{ESN:"ESN4",G03:1},{ESN:"ESN3",G03:2}];
const arr2d = data.reduce((arr,obj)=>(arr.push(Object.values(obj)),arr),[["ESN","G03"]]);
console.info(arr2d)
```

Comment: hi. yes this very helpful. it helps me to convert an array. but just want to know. Instead of using [["ESN","G03"]] , I use [key] . 
my original data is [ESN: "ESN1", G03: 0, G04: 1, G05: 0]
then my key will be ["G03", "G04", "G05", "ESN"]
do you have any idea why would the ESN be at last position?

Comment: @Norain Hmmm... no But order isn't guaranteed in a object. Better to ask a new question with  [mcve]

Comment: i manage to solve it already. thanks. your solution was great for me.